# Why are my inner object property names not camel cased?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm struggling with a serialization problem.

I have a column in a SQL table that contains a pascal cased JSON fragment:

```
{
  "HistoryOpertions": [
    {
      "OperationTitle": "Titre Op",
      "OperationDetails": "Details Op"
    },
    {
      "OperationTitle": "2",
      "OperationDetails": "Op 2"
    },
    {
      "OperationTitle": "by Ol",
      "OperationDetails": "Test",
      "OperateurName": "Olivier Matrot",
      "TimeStamp": 637100138608377997
    }
  ],
  "TimestampLastModification": "2019-11-29T11:09:16.1621275Z",
  "AlertInstructions": [
    {
      "InstructionId": 1,
      "OperateurName": null,
      "CheckPoint": false,
      "TimeStamp": null
    }
  ],
  "AlertTitle": "Alerte safe protect",
  "LiftingDoubtId": 2,
  "SupportId": 3
}
```

I have the following code that parse this fragment, apply some modifications crates a new object and serialize it back to a string. This time I want property names to be camel cased:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(existingAlertDetailEntity.SafeProtectCustomInfo ?? "{}");

JArray alertInstructions = json["AlertInstructions"] as JArray;
foreach (var instruction in alertInstructions)
{
    if (instruction[nameof(AlertInstruction.InstructionId)].ToObject<int>() == model.InstructionId)
    {
        bUpdated = true;
        instruction[nameof(AlertInstruction.TimeStamp)] = model.Status ? DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks : (long?)null;
        instruction[nameof(AlertInstruction.OperateurName)] = model.Status ? user.DisplayName : null;
        instruction[nameof(AlertInstruction.CheckPoint)] = model.Status;
        break;
    }
}
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
string jsonToBeReturned = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new {
        model.AlertId,
        AlertInstructions = JArray.FromObject(
        json["AlertInstructions"],
        JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        })),
    }, jsonSerializer);
```

And here is the result:

```
{
   "alertId":1295041,
   "alertInstructions":[
      {
         "InstructionId":1,
         "TimeStamp":637111473877506411,
         "OperateurName":"Olivier Matrot",
         "CheckPoint":true
      },
      {
         "InstructionId":2,
         "TimeStamp":637112167087671938,
         "OperateurName":"Olivier Matrot",
         "CheckPoint":true
      }
   ]
}
```

We can see that the alertInstructions array still contains Pascal Cased property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deserialize your JSON using an `ExpandoObject`, modify that and serialize it to a string.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(JSON);

// modify your structure here...
json.AlertInstructions[0].TimeStamp = 1234;

var jsonToBeReturned = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    AlertId = 42,
    AlertInstructions  = json.AlertInstructions
}, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

See also the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7QeVa4) for an example.